# Change File Permissions of File via Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, file-permissions

I am trying to change permissions on a file through Powershell, and am having trouble figuring out how to get this to work.

```
$path1 = "\\somepath1\somefile1"
$path2 = "\\somepath2\somefile2"
$acl = Get-Acl $path1
$access_rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("User","Write","ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit","None","Deny")
$acl.SetAccessRule($access_rule)
$acl | Set-Acl $path2
```

`"User"` is a specified usergroup, of many users, and is called something different in the actual code. This throws two errors:

> Exception calling "SetAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): Some or all identity references could not be translated."
>
> Set-Acl : Some or all identity references could not be translated.

Then, I try to dumb the code down, essentially trying to copy permissions of one file to another:

```
$path1 = "\\somepath1\somefile1"
$path2 = "\\somepath2\somefile2"
Get-Acl -Path $path1 | Set-Acl -Path $path2
```

Even this throws an error:

> Set-Acl : Some or all identity references could not be translated.

If I understand these errors correctly, then my `"User"` is not being properly defined. I try to get the `"User"` info  by running the `Get-ADUser` [cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps), but the [ActiveDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/?view=win10-ps) module must not be installed, because I receive this error:

> Get-ADUser : The term 'Get-AdUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,.........

My main question now, is how can I get the user SID information to properly change the permissions on the file? Am I missing a step somewhere? Is there a better way to change file permissions? Can I even try to change permissions for a group? I have hit a wall trying to find a solution, lol.

I have looked at the following sources for help:

[link](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/2e2dzx/exception_calling_addaccessrule_with_1_arguments/)
[link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/ba1d7e0c-0ffb-402d-9839-2f658433b105/how-can-i-set-permissions-with-powershell-?forum=winserverpowershell)
[link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/6c2868f2-9cdf-41d9-beb4-a85579d12c23/ps-script-to-extract-samaccountname-name-title-and-department-from-username?forum=winserverpowershell)
[link](https://rohnspowershellblog.wordpress.com/tag/powershellaccesscontrol/)
[link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2010/11/12/how-to-handle-ntfs-folder-permissions-security-descriptors-and-acls-in-powershell/)
[link](http://www.coretekservices.com/20130613powershell-how-to-discover-and-set-permissions-on-a-folder/)
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440115/powershell-folder-permission-error-some-or-all-identity-references-could-not-b)
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42726564/exception-calling-setaccessrule-with-1-arguments-powershell-error)

Comment: in the get-acl -examples text I saw this:

 The second command uses Set-Acl to apply the security descriptor of Dog.txt to Cat.txt. When the command completes, the ACLs of the Dog.txt and Cat.txt files are identical.

 Example 3: Apply a security descriptor to multiple files

 PS C:\>$NewAcl = Get-Acl File0.txt

 PS C:\>Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp" -Recurse -Include "*.txt" -Force | Set-Acl -AclObject $NewAcl    

Notice the Set-Acl -AclObject not -Path

Comment: Are you referring to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-acl?view=powershell-6)? When I run `Get-Acl -Path $path1 | Set-Acl -AclObject $path2`, I get an `Invalid Argument` error for `AclObject` in `Set-Acl`.

Comment: The problem is with the FileSystemAccessRule expecting 5 parameters , I found this post that covers it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543127/powershell-setting-advanced-ntfs-permissions. I am playing with it myself, to see if I can get it to work.

Comment: The  Get-Acl -Path $path1 | Set-Acl -Path $path2 works fine for me, but you are right the  $acl.SetAccessRule($access_rule) seems to throw that error everytime, despite the New-Object Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule working perfectly.

Comment: Yes, I can get the access rule, and see what its contents are: `$access_rule | fl`

Comment: `Get-Acl -Path $path1 | Set-Acl -Path $path2` still throws an error, lol.

Comment: My experiences with `Set-ACL` are bad. Many times I get strange errors. Instead of Set-ACL I always call the member function `SetAccessControl` from the DirectoryInfo object. For instance: `$ACL=Get-ACL $path1;(Get-Item $path2).SetAccessControl($ACL)`  Hope this helps

Comment: @GertJanKraaijeveld, the code snippet you gave me did not throw an error, but the permissions did not change.